# Provide two versions of build.gradle (stable and experimental)

Tags: android, gradle

I am having to create forks for Android libraries I'm using and updating their `build.gradle` files to support the format of the `gradle-experimental` plugin.

Instead of maintaining forks just for the different configuration format, is there a way to provide both in a library?